# If less than 1 month convert timestamp to time ago in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sure there are many similar questions but I already tried many of them it seems impossible to get the results I want. So what I want is to convert the timestamp on my WordPress posts to show "1 minute ago, 1 day ago, 1 week ago etc." but only if the date is equal or less than 1 month, otherwise to display the normal date.

EDIT: So far it shows only like this

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

```
$posted = get_the_time('U');

if( (int)get_the_time( 'm' ) <= 1 ) {
    echo human_time_diff($posted, current_time( 'U' )). " ago";
} else {
    the_time('j F Y');
}
```

Comment: so far it shows the date only in format like "20 June 2020". I need to display x ago if is less than 1 month.

Comment: Your current if condition makes little sense. Right now, you are checking if the month of the current date is <= 1, so you would be showing the human time diff all through January, and not in any other month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can then check if the timestamp assigned to `$posted` is greater i.e. more recent than the timestamp of a month ago.

if it is more recent, then convert it to a human time ago and append the word `ago` if its not more recent then use the `date('d F Y)` or whatever format you want long dates to appear in to convert the timestamp back to a readable date.

```
<?php
    $posted = get_post_time();
    $date = $posted >= strtotime('-1 month') ? human_time_diff($posted) . ' ago' : date('d F Y', $posted);
?>

<?php echo $date; ?>
```

Returns the expected date format of time ago for dates less than 1 month ago, and the full date for dates longer than 1 month ago...

See image for example.
[image: wordpress example]

Comment: Yes now is working but not with the one you posted before. I guess the conditional was the issue. PS: if you are on windows 10 you can press win + shift + s and you can screenshot only the part you need on your screen. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry mate, one more issue..as in your screenshot as well, I've just created a post and it shows 15 hours ago instead of 1 minute ago. Any fix for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216571/discussion-between-luke-and-komi).